# SQL Replication - does adding a filter require re-initialization?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have an existing publication that has aroung 15 articles (tables)
Some of these tables have 2+ million rows, so obviously, I would like to filter them.

If I set a filter on some of these, will I need to re-initialize the publication before it's effective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as i found out, is yes.

Answer (score 0):

For tables (articles) with existing data I believe you will need to re-initialize. If you are adding new articles you may be able to use the the `@force_reinit_subscription` parameter of `sp_addmergefilter` to add a filtered article without requiring a re-initialization.